# Failed to decode output: Error: overflow (fault=\"overflow\", operation=\"toNumber\"

Tags: solidity, remix, mint

I have a function to mint no of NFTs got in function parameter randomly. My Logic is Below: It is giving the following error as TX.

**Output**:

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
```

**Note**: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

The decoded output shows:

```
{
    "error": "Failed to decode output: Error: overflow (fault=\"overflow\", operation=\"toNumber\", value=\"35408467139433450592217433187231851964531694900788300625387963629091585785856\", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)"
}
```

Solidity code:

```
function CryptoRandomMint(address user_addr, uint noOfMints)  contractIsNotPaused public payable returns (uint[] memory,string[] memory) {
     require(noOfMints<4 && noOfMints>0,"You can mint 1-3 NFTs");
     require(TotalNFTsMinted<1000, "Max Minting Limit reached");
     require(msg.value == mintFees*noOfMints, "Not Enough Balance");
     uint[] memory x; 
     string[] memory y;
        for(uint i=0;i<noOfMints;++i){
            (x[i], y[i]) = randomMinting(user_addr);
        }
        depositAmount(_msgSender(), msg.value);
        return (x,y);    
 
    }
```

Anyone can help what is the issue?

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301960/unable-to-call-contract-function-from-web3-with-big-number-as-parameter

Comment: Can't Understand. I cant figure out my point of error. I am using no bigInt in my whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Solildity expects length for every memory array created inside the function.
In your code include length to memory arrays `x` and `y` .
I assume `noOfMints` will be length of both `x` and `y`, Then the code can be modified as:

```
uint[] memory x = new uint[](noOfMints);
string[] memory y= new string[](noOfMints);
```